# Is marking an interface method as async the right thing todo in my case

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, c#-5.0

I am working with a custom framework wich is used for a long time within my company.
I want to use the new async feature within my code.

In order todo this i have to mark the "ProcessRequestMessage" of "MyClass" as async.
I can't change the interface "IFramework" and class "FrameworkBase".

The Framework expects already that "ProcessRequestMessage" finishes asynchronously so i don't have to use "Wait()" on the End of the method.
A call to "SetResponseCode" signalizes to the framework to finalize the instance of "MyClass"

Question:
I read in the documentation of the async feature that only void Events should be marked as async for Entry into the async workflow (Task does not apply here). My code requires that i mark the implementation of a void interface method as Entry point.

So can i do this:

```
interface IFramework
{
    void ProcessRequestMessage()

    void SetResponseCode(int code)
}

public abstract class FrameworkBase: IFramework
{
    abstract void ProcessRequestMessage()

    public void SetResponseCode(int code)
    {
        //internal implementation
    }
}

public class MyClass: FrameworkBase
{

    protected override async void ProcessRequestMessage()
    {
        //await something

        SetResponseCode(0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two major reasons why you should avoid `async void`:

1. The calling code assumes the method has completed when it has returned.
2. How it handles exceptions.

In your particular case, the calling code does *not* assume the operation has completed when `ProcessRequestMessage` returns, so you *can* use `async void` but you must be very careful with your exceptions. (I prefer using task continuations instead of `async void`).

I recommend writing a `FrameworkTaskBase` just for this:

```
public class FrameworkTestBase: FrameworkBase
{
  protected abstract Task ProcessRequestMessageAsync();
  protected override sealed void ProcessRequestMessage()
  {
    ProcessRequestMessageAsync().ContinueWith(t =>
    {
      if (t.IsFaulted || t.IsCanceled)
        SetResponseCode(-1);
      else
        SetResponseCode(0);
    });
  }
}

public class MyClass: FrameworkBase
{
  protected override async Task ProcessRequestMessageAsync()
  {
    //await something
  }
}
```

Alternatively (using `async void`):

```
public class FrameworkTestBase: FrameworkBase
{
  protected abstract Task ProcessRequestMessageAsync();
  protected override sealed async void ProcessRequestMessage()
  {
    try
    {
      await ProcessRequestMessageAsync();
      SetResponseCode(0);
    }
    catch
    {
      SetResponseCode(-1);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The OP mentions they need `async` for support with their own custom framework, the impression I got was the notion of `Task`/`Task<T>` didn't even come into this.

Comment: The natural return type of `async` is `Task` or `Task<T>`. `void` is an unnatural return type for `async`. So, `Task` is involved by the nature of `async`.

Comment: I agree, however, given this is to work with some custom framework I would say this is a bit of an exception.

Comment: @StephenCleary I ended up using the "Alternative" you posted. I am aware about the the special attention to exceptions in this case. So i think i covered both of your points. Maybe it would have been better if the language designers for the async feature would have completely prohibit the use of void with async. This would force developer to write more code but at least exception could not so easily leak out (covered in the tasks properties). Thanks anyway.

Comment: @rudimenter: When the `async`/`await` feature was originally designed, it did not include support for `async void`. It was added later (over the language team's objections) to enable asynchronous event handlers.